# android retrofit timeout, but works on chrom

Tags: android, http, kotlin, retrofit

I'm sending a get request from my app using retrofit.

```
interface ServerApiService {
    @GET("/screenshot")
    fun getImageAsync(): Deferred<ResponseBody>
}

object ServerApi {
    lateinit var retrofitService: ServerApiService

    fun initialize(baseUrl: HttpUrl) {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .build()
        retrofitService = retrofit.create(ServerApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

```
val imageDeferred = ServerApi.retrofitService.getImageAsync()
val response = imageDeferred.await()
```

When I send the get to `10.0.2.2:5001` I get the following error

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.0.0.2 (port
> 5001) from /10.0.2.16 (port 33422) after 10000ms

But when I type the URL on chrome in the emulator it works and I get the Image (in much less time than 10 seconds).

I tried both HTTP and https and neither of them worked.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: When are you calling `initialize()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to connect to `10.0.2.2:5001` but you get `failed to connect to /10.0.0.2 (port 5001)`, I think it's obvious that baseUrl you provide is wrong (it has a 0 instead of 2).